# How to use UNION of more than one table in JOIN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I need union more than one table in a select's join clause,given below is a sample

```
select .. ... 
from table_a inner join (/*here i want to join two tables(ex. table_c and table_b)*/ )  -- not i am using left join also which is in another condition
where /*some condtitions*/
```

how this is possible ?

Comment: You should edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: It's unclear what you are after. Please edit the question to provide the necessary information or delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to do this?

```
select ...
from   table_a join
       (select ... from table_b
        union
        select ... from table_c) t on table_a.col = t.col
```

That sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

JOIN is a binary operator, so you may join two tables or views at a time. In order to join three tables, you can join two of them and then join the result with the third one.

It's like addition: to sum up three numbers, you add the second to the first, and then add the third to the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
    table_a a
     inner join
    table_b b on a.id= b.id
     inner join 
    table_c c on b.id= c.id
 where /*some conditions*/;
```